# Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. _Pnext was 0xC

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program for class that basically runs page replacement algorithms 1000 times to show which has fewer average page faults. My problem is with an error I recieve from xmemory.
[image]

The code is reduced to areas where the error consistently occurs. 
checkFrames() checks an array to see if it already contains the inputString[i].
frames1, frames2, etc. are arrays that the input is being assigned to according to the algorithm, each of size corresponding their number. 
randomInputString() is just how it sounds.

```
constexpr auto INPUTNUM = 10;
list<int> framesLRU;
list<int>::iterator it;

int frames = 1;

void LRU()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < INPUTNUM; i++)
    {
        bool inFrames = checkFrames(inputString[i]);
        if (inFrames == true)
        {
            it = find(framesLRU.begin(), framesLRU.end(), frameRep);
            framesLRU.erase(it);
            framesLRU.push_back(frameRep);
        }
        else
        {
            int frameUpdate = framesLRU.front();
            framesLRU.pop_front();
            framesLRU.push_back(frameUpdate);

            switch (frames)
            {
            case 1:
                frames1[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 2:
                frames2[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 3:
                frames3[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 4:
                frames4[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 5:
                frames5[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 6:
                frames6[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            case 7:
                frames7[frameUpdate] = inputString[i];
                break;
            }

            pageFaults++;
        }

        if ((i < frames) && (inputString[i] == 0))
            pageFaults++;
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        randomInputString();
        frames = 1;
        do
        {
            runLRU(i);
            frames++;
        } while (frames <= 7);
    }

    printTable();

    return 0;
}
```

The error always happens in the 59th iteration of i in the for loop in main, but within the do while loop it seems random as to when it occurs.
Although it does seem to be happening here:

```
it = find(framesLRU.begin(), framesLRU.end(), frameRep);
framesLRU.erase(it);
framesLRU.push_back(frameRep);
```

within the LRU() function. The iteration of i and the value of frames does not seem to be consistent for the error.

Edit: I figured out the problem. It was an error on my part with how I was assigning values in an array.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. What you have provided is far from minimal.

Comment: I agree, but I have no idea why I am receiving the error. I did provide specific locations for my areas of concern in hopes it would help minimize the amount of code needed to read.

Comment: 1) "_I did provide specific locations for my areas of concern_" 99% of the times, the problem doesn't lie in the area of concern provided by the asker. 2) "_but I have no idea why I am receiving the error._" Sure, but did you read through the link, that I provided, so you could learn of techniques, to reduce the code, without knowing where the error is?

Comment: You should check whether `find` found something. You can't `erase` the end iterator.